# coding dependant inputs or elements in form

Tags: angularjs

What is the best way to code dependent checkboxes/selects.
For example toggle checkboxes state according to other checkboxes state and so on.

For example i need to change some fields when user changes select
User chose food type and i want three fields to become candies types or teas type.

Should i do something like this?

array like:

```
foods_data: 
            {
                type: "sweets",
                food1: "chocolates",
                food2: "candies",
                food3: "cakes"
            },
            {
                name: "teas",
                food1: "black",
                food2: "green",
                food3: "red"
            }
```

define select as

```
<select ng-model="food_select"
ng-options="food as food.name for food in foods_data"
name="food_select" class="input"></select>
```

And set 3 fields ng-models dependent on select like this:

```
//field1
<input id="food1" class="input" type="text" ng_model="food_select.food1">
//field2
<input id="food2" class="input" type="text" ng_model="food_select.food2">
//field3
<input id="food3" class="input" type="text" ng_model="food_select.food3">
```

In this way, as i understand all dependencies will be handled by angular, what is good i think? But code hard to understand.

Or i better add $watch function to controller and apply field dependencies inside there?

**What is the best code practices to do such things in angular?**

Comment: I use $watch when the dependencies require some calculation to run to determine what to update the other models with. If all you need is two data binding, then Maxim Shoustin solution fine. If you want re usability, you may need to look into directives using the NgModelController + FormController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or i better add $watch function to controller and apply field dependencies inside there?

No, in your case you don't need `$watch`. The `ng-model` (as big advantage of Angular) will do this work for you. We have here 3 inputs with different `ng-model`s that based on `ng-options` selected item.

The model you posted (`foods_data: {..}`) will be hard to maintain because each item has different structure: `type: "sweets",` and `name: "teas"`. Decide what you prefer `name` or `types` or create somethig generic like:

```
foods_data: 
        {
            type: {
                  name:"sweets"
                  },
            food1: "chocolates",
            food2: "candies",
            food3: "cakes"
        },
        {
            type: {
                   name:"teas"
                  },
            food1: "black",
            food2: "green",
            food3: "red"
        }
```

If I understand you right (your question is too global) you try to do something like: Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/625/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
 <select ng-model="selectedItem"
ng-options="selectedItem as selectedItem.type.name for selectedItem in foods_data"
 class="input"></select>

    <input id="food1" class="input" type="text" ng_model="selectedItem.food1">
<input id="food2" class="input" type="text" ng_model="selectedItem.food2">
<input id="food3" class="input" type="text" ng_model="selectedItem.food3">
```

when **controller**

```
 $scope.foods_data =[ 
            {
        type: {
              name:"sweets"
              },
        food1: "chocolates",
        food2: "candies",
        food3: "cakes"
    },
    {
        type: {
               name:"teas"
              },
        food1: "black",
        food2: "green",
        food3: "red"
    } ];

    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.foods_data[0];
```

Comment: "No, in your case you don't need $watch." I don't need watch cause tasks is too easy? In what situations watches are more preferable?

Comment: `watch` is good when you use service model and 2 controllers, for example. When one controller change value in Service you want to notify other controller about and we can use watch. Or you want to stay with 2 different ng-models but sync 2 textfields like: http://plnkr.co/edit/5zqkj7iYloeHYkzK1Prt?p=preview